# unable to run plumber R on google cloud Rstudio pro server

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, rstudio, plumber

I am using plumber on rstudio pro on google cloud platform.
below code works fine on my local machine i.e. I am able to view swagger UI at the link provided but does not work on google cloud platform.

```
# plumber.R

#' Echo the parameter that was sent in
#' @param msg The message to echo back.
#' @get /echo
function(msg="")
{
  list(msg = paste0("The message is: '", msg, "'"))
}

#' Plot out data from the iris dataset
#' @param spec If provided, filter the data to only this species (e.g. 'setosa')
#' @get /plot
#' @png
function(spec)
{
  myData <- iris
  title <- "All Species"

  # Filter if the species was specified
  if (!missing(spec)) 
    {
    title <- paste0("Only the '", spec, "' Species")
    myData <- subset(iris, Species == spec)
    }

  plot(myData$Sepal.Length, myData$Petal.Length,
       main=title, xlab="Sepal Length", ylab="Petal Length")
}
```

I run plumber script and get below output

```
> pr$run(port = 8000 )
Starting server to listen on port 8000
Running the swagger UI at http://127.0.0.1:8000/__swagger__/
```

When I use the link above I get below error , although it works fine on my local

```
 HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.
```

Plumber docs, suggested to check if there is firewall in place as we are running in remote server but on google cloud I could not find any firewall rule blocking this.

Please suggest what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

http://127.0.0.1 is your localhost. When your run in the cloud you have to use the ip of the cloud machine of the RStudio Pro instances and to make sure that it is exposed and available to you. Also plumber only accept http request so your cloud machine have to accept http request.

Are you using the vm from the marketplace?

Comment: yes I am using GCP marketplace VM i.e. Rstudiopro on compute engine